# Can implicit conversion by Lisp's FORMAT function be controlled?

Tags: floating-point, format, lisp, common-lisp

While trying to round a fraction to 9 digits, I came across the following:

```
? (format t "~9$" 763700091/112000148)
6.818742300
Nil
```

But the rounding is only accurate to 5 digits. I expected `format` would take care of this automatically; ie, convert the fraction to double precision given the number of digits required to represent it, but apparently `format` doesn't work that way. If you coerce this fraction to double, you get:

```
? (coerce 763700091/112000148 'double-float)
6.818741802019762D0
```

Is there a control directive to instruct `format` to use double precision in this case. Or must I coerce the fraction into `double-float` before passing it to format to accomplish this?

I know `format` is fiendishly complex and you could certainly accomplish this by calling an external function, but I'm hoping to get away with a simpler tweak to `~9$`

Comment: I don't think so. If the argument is not a `FLOAT` it's always coerced to `SINGLE-FLOAT`. There's no way to override this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation on the format string](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/22_cca.htm) states:

> If arg is a rational number, then it is coerced to be a single float
>   and then printed.

Thus the answer to your question is **no**, however you can easily combine what you have done to round the number that you just have coerced to a double float:

```
(format nil "~9$" (coerce 763700091/112000148 'double-float))
; ==> "6.818741802"
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible. From [CLHS 22.3.3.4 Tilde Dollarsign: Monetary Floating-Point](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/22_ccd.htm)

> If arg is a rational number, then it is coerced to be a single float and then printed.

No provision is provided to specify an alternate type to coerce to.